# ATtiny85 - report error "Device reports version as: 2.2"

Tags: bootloader, attiny

I've bought ATtiny, from [see link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32584084654.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.459ed540M9V5c7&algo_pvid=e91a8f78-fe84-44a2-9aab-859c070bbf1f&algo_expid=e91a8f78-fe84-44a2-9aab-859c070bbf1f-0&btsid=0be3743b15889238058037747e8a9d&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_).
Trying to upload a basic `Blink` sketch I get this error: `Device reports version as: 2.2`.

1) Board manager was updated using `http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json`

2) Board selected as `Digispark (Default -16.5MHz )`

3) Programmer set to `Micronocleus`

Tried using some guides on-line, but some were old, some were for windows, while I'm using Ubuntu machine.

Appreciate any help,
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a newer board than the version of Micronucleus in the Arduino package.

As I discovered [here](http://digistump.com/board/index.php/topic,1834.msg8364.html#msg8364) you basically need to upgrade micronucleus in your Ardino installation, which you can download from [here](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus)

- Download the zip file from Github and extract it.  Then in a terminal (if you're not already in one) go to the directory you extracted.
- Build the executable by typing "make"
- Copy the compiled executable to `~/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/<version>/`

where `<version>` is the currently installed version number (e.g., `2.0a4`).  There should already be a `micronucleus` executable in there that you would replace with your newly compiled one.

Comment: a `\2.04a' directory was inside that path you noted ( was added after adding digistumb's board manager

Comment: @Guy.D Where abouts in the path?

Comment: `micronucleus` after built was move to noted directory. But directory already contains an instance of micronucleus, inside a directory `2.0a4`. Should I delete it ? ( didn't help ). Seemed that didn't matter

Comment: Replace the existing one with your newly compiled one

Comment: `guy@desktop:~/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus$ ls -l
total 60
drwxrwxr-x 2 guy guy  4096 May  8 16:06 2.0a4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 guy guy 55616 May  8 17:40 micronucleus`

Comment: after deleting I get this error msg: "

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "___REMOVE___/launcher": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
 at processing.app.helpers.ProcessUtils.exec(ProcessUtils.java:11)
 at cc.arduino.packages.Uploader.executeUploadCommand(Uploader.java:129)
 at 
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
 ... 11 more
An error occurred while uploading the sketch'

Comment: Did you replace the existing one with the new one, or put the new one up a directory? I have modified my answer

Comment: I have deleted entire `2.04` lib, and pasted 1 executable file that was created by `make`

Comment: Make the directory again and move the file into it.

Comment: that solved it !!!! thank you !!!